# How can I merge data-frame rows by different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with 200k rows and some 50 columns with same id in different columns, looking like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pic': [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0]
                          , 'story': [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
                          , 'des': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]
                          , 'some_another_value': [2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1]
                          , 'some_value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

   pic  story  des  some_another_value  some_value
0    1      0    0                   2           nan
1    0      1    0                   nan         2
2    0      0    1                   nan         3
3    0      2    0                   nan         4
4    2      0    0                   4           nan
5    0      0    2                   nan         6
6    3      0    0                   1           nan
7    0      0    3                   nan           8
8    0      3    0                   nan           9
```

I would like to merge the rows which have the same value in 'pic' 'story' 'des'

```
   pic  story  des  some_another_value  some_value
0    1      1    1                   2           5
3    2      2    2                   4           10
6    3      3    3                   1           17
```

How can this be achieved?

*I am looking for a solution which not contain a for loop

*Prefer not a sum method

Comment: Your code provide different data than that printed below it. Also, can `pic, story, des` have values `1, 1, 0` or `1, 2, 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say *Prefer not a sum method* when your expected output data clearly indicate sum. For your sample data, in each row, exactly one of `pic, story, des` is zero, so:

```
df.groupby(df[['pic','story', 'des']].sum(1)).sum()
```

gives

```
   pic  story  des  some_another_value  some_value
1    1      1    1                 2.0         5.0
2    2      2    2                 4.0        10.0
3    3      3    3                 1.0        17.0
```